# Invalid syntax using exec function

Tags: python

My exec is not working

here is my code:

```
b = ('''def peter:
if nname == "peter":
    return "you are a cool boy"
else:
    return "you are a not cool boy"
def weight:
if weight > 100:
    return "you weight too much"
else:
    return
     "you weight good"
'''
exec(b)
```

when i run it, it highlights the e in exec and says "invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1):

you have opening bracket in starting which you havent closed,

also your def syntax is not correct you have to prepare it very carefully.

try this:

```
b ='''
def peter():
    if nname == "peter":
        return "you are a cool boy"
    else:
        return "you are a not cool boy"
def weight():
    if weight > 100:
        return "you weight too much"
    else:
        return "you weight good"
'''
exec(b)
```

Comment: it works but when i run it it does not print anything

Comment: @Goose all you're doing is defining two functions, never calling them, therefore nothing will be printed by the exec call

Comment: @GooseHjonk you have to call the functions then only it will run. I suggest you to first learn basics of python and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your Syntax is wrong.

```
b ='''
def peter():
    if nname == "peter":
        return "you are a cool boy"
    else:
        return "you are a not cool boy"
def weight():
    if weight > 100:
        return "you weight too much"
    else:
        return "you weight good"
'''
exec(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have created a variable named nname and weight before creating these two function. If not then create them first.

```
def peter(nname):# You also need to pass the variable nname in function Peter
    if nname == "peter":
        return "you are a cool boy"
    else:
        return "you are a not cool boy"
def weight(weight):# You also need to pass the variable weight in function weight.
   if weight > 100:
       return "you weight too much"
   else:
       return "you weight good"
weight(weight)
peter(nname)# Calling functions
```

The code should be like this. To define a function in Python the following syntax is used.

```
def func_name(variable1, variable2):#Creating function
     #Your code
func_name(variable1, variable2)#Calling functions
```

You can learn more about Python functions:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functions-in-python/